# img not showing in Safari in attempt to make img map responsive

Tags: html, css, safari, responsive-design

removing the float:left did not have any effect :-(

I'm trying to make an imagemap responsive on the following page:
http://fietsklik.company12.com/index.php/how-it-works 
The first image is the imgmap, under that the responsive version.
On Chrome it seems to do what I want it to do, but on Safari 6.0.4, the three images on the right do not show up. Please advise.

The code for the responsive 'img-map' is the following:

```
<div class="hiw-container">
<img class="hiw-container-img1" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/perfectum/howitworks.jpg"}}" alt="" width="649px" height="500px" />
<img class="hiw-container-img2" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/perfectum/howitworks.jpg"}}" alt="" width="330px" height="166px" /> 
<img class="hiw-container-img3" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/perfectum/howitworks.jpg"}}" alt="" width="330px" height="166px" /> 
<img class="hiw-container-img4" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/perfectum/howitworks.jpg"}}" alt="" width="330px" height="167px" />
</div>
```

And the css that goes along with it:

```
.hiw-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 51.02%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

.hiw-container-img1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 66%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left
}

.hiw-container-img2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 34%;
    height: 33%;
    float: right !important;
    padding-left: 200px;
}

.hiw-container-img3 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 34%;
    height: 33%;
    float: right !important;
    padding-left: 200px;
}

.hiw-container-img4 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 34%;
    height: 34%;
    float: right !important;
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions what might cause the images of hiw-container-img2 to img4 not showing in Safari?
(using Safari 6.0.4)

Comment: Showing up fine on Safari 5.1.7 on my PC.

Comment: Thanks for checking, the problem is shows in Safari 6.0.4

Comment: What happens if you remove the `height: 0;` from the `.hiw-container` class?

Comment: The 3 img's on the right do show up, but it makes the img on the left twice as long as it should be.
edit: Tried removing the     height: 0; and adding a     max-height to the img-1 , and it works for standard resolutions but gives a similar problem when scaling down resolution

Comment: Hey @GarethCornish the edit of removing the float: left; did not have the desired (or any) effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from this, your images 2, 3 and 4 are correctly sizing themselves to 34% of their parent, which is 0. Image 1 is not doing this, possibly because it is positioned absolutely. Instead, it is ignoring all sizing instructions (even those in the tag itself), and simply making its height proportional to its width (which is behaving correctly).

If you remove the `height: 0;` from the parent class, images 2, 3 and 4 size correctly, but image 1 is sizing itself at 100% of its original height (500px, set in the HTML).

My suggestion is to not set the heights on any of the images specifically, and just let them size proportionally. Because you've set specific heights in the HTML, you need to override that with a `height: auto;` directive. The example below will work only if the three side images are sized so that they fit exactly next to the main image (ie: the sum of their heights is the same as the height of the main) when scaled at 34%:66%. If not, the last image may align below all the others:

```
.hiw-container {
    overflow: hidden;   
}

.hiw-container-img1 { 
    width: 66%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.hiw-container-img2 {
    width: 34%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}

.hiw-container-img3 {
    width: 34%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}

.hiw-container-img4 {
    width: 34%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Works as expected now in all browsers.